# Add style to specific streets for Bus Route

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I love the street and feature color styling in APIv3.
Is there a way to color a specific steet(s) ie. for a bus route? 
Polylines obscure the streetname and are visually unappealing.
If no simple way, is it possible create sub-maps (overlays perhaps) within a map to style sub-regions?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think that's only possible  to color: Highways, local and arterials routes, but you can color points of interests and bus stations, a specific street is only possible to color using the polylines, and directions service, and down the opacity of the line. =/

Try to look [this site](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), it's a visual editing of the map, easy to use all possibilities of [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling), it auto generate the style script to you use on your map.

For more infos: [Gmap3.net](http://gmap3.net/api/set-styled-map.html)

Comment: Thanks for you response.  Yup, already used that styled map thing map. It's cool. But obvioulsly not as street specific as I require.